# DIsable Eset Smart Security

Tags: cmd, antivirus, nod32

I want to know if is possible to disable Eset Smart Security 7 using command prompt without system privileges, and if that so, How?

I have tried using

```
taskkill /F /IM egui.exe
```

also

```
net config ekrn start= disabled
```

but seems it cant be done without system privileges.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and is off-topic here. However, the answer would be "No". If it were, there would be no "security" (if just any old batch file or command could disable it without having privileges), would there?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This isn't really a question about programming, but if it is possible to kill Eset's services without privilege escalation, that's a pretty huge bug on their part. It's probably not possible through simple one liners in the command prompt.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer. ("if it is possible, it wouldn't be good" isn't really a definitive answer.) You're correct that the question is off-topic here as well.

Comment: I would comment if I had the reputation to do so. ( you need 50 to comment on something that isn't mine )

Comment: You are not allowed to use answers as a way to circumvent not having sufficient reputation to comment. If you really need to post comments, work a little harder to get that extra 17 reputation to enable that privilege. :-) There's also a risk involved; there are people here who will downvote answers that aren't really answers (such as this one), which can cost you the rep you have earned.

Comment: It might not be a 'programming question' but still of importance to those in the business. After all, we all need AV protection. Is there an appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: @SteveStaple I think superuser.com will accept questions of this sort. Although I'll have to admit figuring out exactly what site you can or cannot ask questions on in the stack exchange network is quite cumbersome.